# Java: TCP/UDP Hole Punching Using Servlet?

Tags: java, networking, servlets

Is it possible for me to implement a client/server networking model that connects via TCP hole punching using a servlet deployed on AppEngine?

If so, how do you forward the connection request from the client to the host and establish a 2-way connection that eradicates the server involvement once initiated?

Comment: Do you need (1) to connect through socket one client with one server that live on AppEngine, or do you need (2) that the application on App Engine act as a broker to connect two clients each other?

Comment: AppEngine needs to act like a broker to the two clients.  The issue I'm having right now is that the servlet getRemotePort() method returns 0, which is invalid.  That may have something to do with the NAT but I'm not sure.

I have a question for that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164342/java-servlet-returns-remote-port-of-0

Answer (score 0):

The last time I need to do something similar I start using [SOHT Socket over HTTP Tunneling](http://www.ericdaugherty.com/dev/soht/).

Then, because the scope of the project was a didactic scope, I also realize my own implementation of a similar logic, where the server part was a very simple `Servlet`.

However you can use directly that library or study its sources to understand how it works.

Comment: I don't think that's really what I'm looking for, but thanks for your answer.