# Java Servlet Returns Remote Port of 0?

Tags: java, android, networking, servlets, tcp

I'm using a servlet deployed on Google AppEngine to respond with the client's remote port number.  HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() works fine, but getRemotePort() returns 0?

Port 0 isn't valid.  I've tried other IP services that told me normal port numbers (i.e. 55046 or something) but my servlet returns 0 every time it is accessed from a browser or from Java code.

My end goal is being able to tell a connection initiator upon lookup the recipient's address and external port location so a TCP hole punching technique will work properly.

What is the reason for this?  How can I get the actual port number (if possible)?  Does a NAT router not use a proxy port?

Comment: It is a [bug](http://googleproof.org/gsubdomainiscode/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4210)

Comment: Well that's annoying.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why getRemotePort would return 0, but for your end goal knowing the client port is useless.  The client port gets reassigned for every connection.  In fact, if the first connection uses 55046, the whole point of the client port is for a new connection to use a different, and unused client port number.

This makes it useless information for configuring a hole in the firewall policy.  You will not need the client port.  What you need is the server port, the server address, and optionally the client address if you only want to allow access from that client address.

Comment: Don't you "punch holes" by having the host initiate a connection to the client address (which fails) and then having the client initiate a connection to the host?  Maybe that only works for UDP...

Comment: By holes, I'm thinking holes in the firewall policy.  I don't know what you are talking about.  I don't know of a protocol where the host initiates a connection to a client.  That would make the host the client and the client would be a server.  So I'm not sure what you mean when you say client, and don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: NAT traversal.  P2P Client ----> Server <----- Host    
|
Client <----- Server -----> Host    
|
Client <-----> Host

Comment: I really meant it when I said I didn't know what you were talking about.  You might know, but then you must be talking about something I don't know.  Although NAT is different than a firewall, it is typically a feature of firewall products, so I think your need is related to the specifics of your NAT product.

Comment: The method used for NAT traversal usually work for 3/4 different types of NAT routers.  This is not specific to my router.